# Modify ActiveRecord attribute only for saving

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Lets assume I have some ActiveRecord instance. How can I get rails to map a field of it before it gets saved in the database but without changing the value of the record in memory?
`before_save` callback seems to modify the value not just for saving it.

This example shows the desired behavior by mapping the field `n` with `n -> n*2` (a reversible mapper)

```rb
x = MyRecord.create(n: 2)
x.n
=> 2
x.save()   # database should now contain value 4 in col n
x.n
=> 2       # value is still 2 (map only affects values in db)
```

More specifically i want to use Marshal.dump & Marshal.load to (de)serialize fields of my records for the database to contain them as blobs.

Comment: Not sure I understand the intent here. What is the expectation for reloading this record e.g. `x = MyRecord.find(x_id)`, should `n` be 2 or 4? Maybe you have over obfuscated the question since you stated "More specifically i want to use Marshal.dump & Marshal.load to (de)serialize fields" which is drastically different. Maybe you are just looking for `def n; Marshall.load(read_attribute("n")); end`  and `def n=(val); write_attribute("n",Marshall.dump(val)); end`?

Comment: "i want to use Marshal.dump & Marshal.load to (de)serialize fields of my records for the database to contain them as blobs", **don't do this**. The marshal format can change when you upgrade Ruby and there's no easy way to read older formats. You're better off storing normalized data rather than serialized data, or use a stable format like JSON and maybe even a database that supports JSON columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, `MyRecord.create(n: 2)` actually will save the record to the DB.

If you want to use custom serialization (e.g. to Marshall between the storage and memory format of the field). Then you can use a custom value type, see: https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Attributes/ClassMethods.html (under Creating Custom Types).

Comment: Thanks for the hint with custom types. It was very helpful. I managed to implement the serialization in a custom type that transforms my Array into Json data as recommended by @mu-is-too-short